# Get raw parameters from react router

Tags: react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Is there any way to get the **raw** (without URL decoding) parameters from the react router **V6.3** without making my own `windows.location.href` parser?

Example:

```
path: /companies/Samsung%2CInc,Lenovo%2CInc

const params = useParams();
const companies = params.companies?.split(',');

Expected:
[
  'Samsung%2CInc',
  'Lenovo%2CInc',
]
Getting:
[
  'Samsung',
  'Inc',
  'Lenovo',
  'Inc',
]
```

Any recommendations here?

PS. React Router does URL Decode, which is what I want to avoid. I found related issue on [lib's issues board](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7173#issuecomment-1186178437).

Comment: What raw parameters are you referring to? Can you provide a more compete [mcve]?

Comment: I just updated the question, and I already found the answer to it, thx to the `react-router` Issues pages.

Comment: Well, I was asking about the *actual* route path params, if you'd declared any. Something like this may be better used in a queryString parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible at this moment. The URL decoding is coming from the matching part, which is a way deeper than `useParams` method.

I created a [workaround gist](https://gist.github.com/Kostanos/e3cc71b6263846cdd887395f505076c8) that uses already parsed params and obtaining their RAW (URL encoded) version from the location.pathname

It works for my case, but I'm sure it could be optimized.